# How to use make_shared to create an array of objects of the same type?

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr, make-shared

We could use "make_shared" to create an object faster and safer compared to use "new". For example,

```
shared_ptr<Dog> p = make_shared<Dog>("Luther").
```

If I need to create an array of objects (e.g. Dog[3]), is it possible to use "make_shared" instead "new"? Besides, is it possible to use a customized delete function with make_shared method?

Comment: If you do not need the _shared_ ownership, `std::vector<Dog>` may suffice. In C++20 `make_shared` can be used with `Dog[]`. I would think a bit harder to eliminate the need for shared ownership at all by structuring my object ownership to have hierarchic lifetimes.

Comment: according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), that's getting addded in c++20 (#4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
auto parr = make_shared<std::array<Dog, 3>>(std::array<Dog, 3>{"Bob", "Charlie", "Alice"});
```

If you want a shared pointer to the nth element...

```
auto pelem = std::shared_ptr<Dog*>{p, p->data()+n};
```

which does 0 allocations.